# I need help implementing a for loop

Tags: c#

I've been trying to implement this into a for loop.  I wrote out a flow chart for this program.  The program needs to repeat until n = 1.  Ive included a link to my flow chart.  If someone could help me out here that would be awesome.

[image]

```
using System;
namespace collatzconjecture
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (n == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", n);


            }
            else if (n % 2 == 0)
            {
                int a = n / 2;
                Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", a);

            }
            else
            {
                int b = 3 * n + 1;
                Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", b);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you struggling with exactly? You can't get much more basic than a simple for loop.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep doing the n/2 or 3*n+1 until n is 1?  If that's the case then you really want a `while` loop, not a `for` loop, or use recursion like your flow chart does.

Comment: The flowchart does not loop.

Comment: When I wrap it in a for loop it either spits out an error, or it repeats infinite times.

Comment: @Romoku Actually it does recursion.

Comment: @juharr And recursion, while *comparable* to a loop, is not itself a loop.

Comment: @Servy Didn't say it was a loop, just pointed out there was recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is a `while` loop that continues until `n` is 1.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", n);
    while(n != 1)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n = n / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            n = 3 * n + 1;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("n = {0}", a);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use `for`, put it straightforward, as it is described:

- start with user input
- break on `n == 1`
- next step is either `3 * n + 1` or `n / 2`

something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  for (int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // start with user input
       n > 1;                                       // safier choice then n != 1
       n = n % 2 == 0 ? n / 2 : 3 * n + 1)          // next step either n/2 or 3*n + 1 
    Console.WriteLine(n);

  Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However, if you can choose the implementation, I suggest extacting logic into a generator:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> Collatz(int n) {
  while (n > 1) {
    yield return n;

    n = n % 2 == 0
      ? n / 2
      : 3 * n + 1;
  }

  yield return n;
}
```

And UI

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Collatz(n)));
}
```

Comment: @Richard Irons: Sorry, but the code extract compiles (one should add `class`, `namespace`) even if `for` loop is quite *unusual*.

Comment: Oh yeah I just realised what you're doing there. Ouch. That's some pretty nasty code.

Comment: @Richard Irons: It is; I hate myself `X` `Y` problems: do `X` using `Y`; for sure `while` loop looks much more natural (but if `for` is *must be* I'll put it as I've done)